# Multisig: Can you add another party after finalize_multisig

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc, multisig

Let's say i'm creating a 2/3 multisig but i only have 2 people, is it possible to create the multisig with only 2 people, then later i add the third person?

and/or can you edit a multisig and change/replace a person?